# Квитирование логов и сбор статистики Rsyslog

Tags: логирование, grafana, kibana, rsyslog

У меня есть Rsyslog, который собирает все логи с сетевого оборудования, и Loganalyzer, который выводит логи в графический интерфейс. Проблема заключается в том, что логи выводятся просто друг за другом, никак не анализируется информация. Например, если одна и та же ошибка появляется, она не стекируется в одну строчку с указанием количества сообщений. Отсутствует подтверждение ошибок и т.д. Подскажите, существует ли ПО по типу grafana или cabana, с помощью которого возможно было бы обрабатывать все логи, как мне необходимо?