# fluentd прием журналов на один порт с последующей обработкой

Tags: fluentd

пробую использовать fluentd для сбора логов с различного сетевого оборудования и отправки в opensearch.
Есть ли возможность получения журналов от всех устройств на один порт, а потом разделить и обработать полученные журналы по имени устройства, которое содержится в сообщении?

Comment: массовые собеседования? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1564837/178576